# Debugging a local gem in REPL

Tags: ruby, debugging, rubygems

I'm developing a gem. I'd like to be able to test it locally without having to create a new project and install it for now. Is there any way to load it into REPL and execute step by step or however it done? The key is that I don't want to install the gem, then edit it, then re-install, I want to debug it without installing, in-place.

Comment: `irb -Ilib` should be all you need, if you are in your gem's repo, and it has usual gem structure. Similar is possible for debugging. How do you *normally* single step code you wish to debug? There are some choices there. I don't work in debug mode though, irb has often been enough (and unit tests of course)

Comment: There's a `gem console` command you can run inside a Gem's directory

Comment: @maxpleaner,     Unknown command console

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. `cd` into the gem directory
2. `irb -Ilib -rgem_name`

Here you go.
For more info check out: http://guides.rubygems.org/make-your-own-gem/